# React Native Flatlist item navigate to new page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to make an app where I can add item in a flatlist . Then each item I can navigate to a new page only for that specific item . In that page, I can add another flatlist.

To explain it more, lets say I add few Classroom item in the flatlist (Classroom A, Classroom B, Classroom C). When I press Clasroom A , it will navigate to a page named Classroom A . In that page, I can add and delete the name of each students using another flatlist.

How can I design the page for the Classsrooms ??? Because when I add the name of the student in classroom A, the names of the students is also available in the flatlist of other Classrooms.

This is my code for the Main Menu:

```
import React, { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Alert,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function MainMenu(){
  const [classroomInput, setClassroomInput] = useState('');
  const [classroom, setClassroom] = useState([]);

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    getClassroom();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    saveClassroom(classroom);
  }, [classroom]);


  const saveClassroom = async (classroom) => {
    try {
      const stringifyClassroom = JSON.stringify(classroom);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('classroom', stringifyClassroom);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getClassroom = async () => {
    try {
      const classrooms = await AsyncStorage.getItem('classroom');
      if (classrooms !== null) {
        setClassroom(JSON.parse(classrooms));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const addClassroom = () => {
    if (classroomInput === ''){
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please input class');
    } else {
      const newClassroom = {
        id: Math.random().toString(),
        Classroom: classroomInput,
      };
      setClassroom([...classroom,newClassroom]);
      setClassroomInput('');

    }
  };

  const deleteClassroom = (classroomId) => {
    const newClassrooms = classroom.filter(item => item.id !== classroomId);
    setClassroom(newClassrooms);
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder={'Add Classrooms'}
      value={classroomInput}
      onChangeText={(text) => setClassroomInput(text)}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addClassroom()} style={styles.button}>
        <Text>Add Classroom</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        data={classroom}
        keyExtractor = { (item) => item.id.toString() }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Classroom', item)}  >
          <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <View>
              <Text style={[styles.classText , {fontSize: 18}]}>
            {item?.Classroom}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View >
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.delete ]} onPress={() => deleteClassroom(classroom?.id)}>
                <Icon name="remove" size={15} color={'#fff'} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  input: {
    width: '70%',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  delete: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff3333',
    padding: 5,
    color: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ff9999',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  listItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '70%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is the code for the classroom:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React, { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Alert,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const Classroom = ( {navigation, route}) => {
    const [studentInput, setStudentInput] = useState('');
    const [student, setStudent] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getStudent();
      }, []);
      useEffect(() => {
        saveStudent(student);
      }, [student]);


      const saveStudent = async (student) => {
        try {
          const stringifyStudent = JSON.stringify(student);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('student', stringifyStudent);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

      const getStudent = async () => {
        try {
          const students = await AsyncStorage.getItem('student');
          if (students !== null) {
            setStudent(JSON.parse(students));
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

    const addStudent = () => {
        if (studentInput === ''){
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Please input student name');
        } else {
          const newStudent = {
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            Name: studentInput,
          };
          setStudent([...student,newStudent]);
          setStudentInput('');

        }
      };

    const deleteStudent = (studentId) => {
        const newStudent = student.filter(item => item.id !== studentId);
        setStudent(newStudent);
    };

    return (
        <View styles={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.goBack()} style={styles.button}>
                <Text>Back</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20}}>[ Classroom Name ]</Text>
            <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'Add Student Name'}
            value={studentInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => setStudentInput(text)}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> addStudent()} style={styles.button}>
                <Text>Add Student</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <FlatList
            style={styles.flatlist}
            data={student}
            keyExtractor = { (item) => item.id.toString() }
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.listItem}>
                <View>
                <Text style={[styles.classText , {fontSize: 18}]}>
                {item?.Name}
                </Text>
                </View>
                <View >
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.delete ]} onPress={() => deleteStudent(item?.id)}>
                    <Icon name="remove" size={15} color={'#fff'} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
            )}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default Classroom;

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
      padding: 8,
    },
    input: {
      width: '70%',
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      marginBottom: 20,
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      padding: 10,
      marginBottom: 10,
    },
    listItem: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      width: '70%',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    delete: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff3333',
        padding: 5,
        color: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ff9999',
        borderRadius: 5,
      },
  });
```

Comment: Wdym *"How can I create the page for the classrooms"*? Do you need help designing it? Please share the existing code and tell us what isn't working like you expected. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry @Elias. i already update my code in the question above . Lets say I add student name James in Classroom A, when I want to add student list of Classroom B, James is inside there too. Actually, he should not be in Classroom B since he is in Classroom A. And also, how can I getParams the name of the classroom ? because i get and error getParam is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `AsyncStorage` key `'student'` regardless of which classroom you are looking at.  You need to keep your student lists separate, so you'll need a separate key for each.  Something like:

```
const key = `students_in_room_${classroomId}`
```

You can get the classroom id (A, B, C) through the `route` prop from your navigation.

---

Edit: You would use this unique `key` instead of the string `'students'` for reading and writing to `AsyncStorage`.  That way you can have separate stored values for each classroom.

```
const students = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
```

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, stringifyStudent);
```

Comment: Can you explain me more about the const key ? I dont know how to implement it in my code .  Later the key constant is put inside the flatlist or where? and thank you for the route prop . I managed to get the classroom name as the page Title.